# Can I put SharedPreferences.edit() in the constructor of my class or it needs to be called everytime the preferences change and get committed?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Do I need to call edit SharedPreferences everytime before I change the preferences and commit or can I do that just once in the costructor?

Is this correct ?

```
public class MyPreferencesClass {

    private Context ctx;

    private static SharedPreferences settings;
    private static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Constructor Class //
    public MyPreferencesClass(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
        settings = ctx.getSharedPreferences(CUSTOM_PREFS_NAME, 0);
        editor = settings.edit(); // Called Only once in constructor not not everytime in edit methods
    }

    public static void setSomePref1(Boolean boolValue) {
        // editor = settings.edit(); Not required everytime
        editor.putBoolean(PREFS_1, boolValue);
        editor.commit();            
    }

    public static void setSomePref2(Boolean boolValue) {
        editor.putBoolean(PREFS_2, boolValue);
        editor.commit();            
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes it is right, whats is the issue ?

Comment: No issue. Wanted to ask before making a batch of changes to my code. Did not want to end up breaking a running(though inefficient) code. Thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be able to use SharedPreferences.Editor instance as long as it's valid so no need to call SharedPreferences#edit() every time.